# How to track web request made to sharepoint site from remote computer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, splistitem, logs

I am trying to connect IBM datastage application to a sharepoint list using soap web services. I am using GetList and Getlistitems to get the data from sharepoint list. While doing this i can sucessfully connect using Getlist function , but getlistitems its throwing the error.

Now i was wondering if there is a way to track the responce made by the IBM Datastage upon my SharePoint Farm. I checked the trace logs, i cant find any trace there.

Where would i find such information to make sure connection between sharepoint server and IBM datastage has been made sucessfully.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can look in the IIS logs. Look at the cs-uri-stem and cs-uri-query fields and you should see your web service calls reaching the web server.

You can also insert a proxy (like Fiddler) to view the traffic leaving your browser.

Comment: Exception happened at 11:22 am but i dont see any activity at that time.

Comment: You are looking at the IIS logs and not the ULS logs, correct?  If there is not activity in the IIS logs, then I think your request did not make it to the web server. Be aware you might need to look in a specific folder for the IIS logs. If you go into IIS manager and click on the advanced settings for your Web site, the ID field will help you figure out which IIS log to look at (assuming you have multiple web sites on your server). If you have multiple Web Front ends, also make sure you are looking at the correct one.